# How does nesting two crontab Contexts work?

Tags: esper, nesper

Is it possible to nest two crontab contexts like these?

```
create context Nest 
context A start (0, *, *, *, 1) end (0, *, *, *, 6),
context B start (0, 8, *, *, *) end (0, 22, *, *, *)
```

Does the first context decide the second context?

If so I assume, A should be the first since it decides the days, and the second will live as long the days are within the first context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. The "A" context controls the "B" context. The "B" context lives only when A lives.

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea how I can determine which shall be the first one? Is there a way to check which crontab is "higher" than the other